# How to make the changes in Large Model

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Dataset now configured as a Large Model.

The question is:

How to make the changes in this dataset - concerning new or existing measures, Power Query, relations, etc.?

Is it possible to have full-value access to this dataset via Power BI Desktop? Similar to older not-Large models.

Will appreciate any kind of help - like documents, tutorials, or direct explanations.